# using multipule variables in a procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

So this should be a very basic one for you.  I have a stored procedure that does a look up via dates.  I want to add in a @storeno variable that can either be one or all of the sores.  How would I do this?

```
USE [POS_REPORT]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReportTotals] (
@fromdate VARCHAR(10),
@todate VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[Description],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[amount] AS 'pos',
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[amount] AS 'ecc',
CASE WHEN [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[amount] = [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[amount] THEN 'BALANCED' ELSE 'UNBALANCED' END AS 'status',
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[responce],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[comment]
FROM
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals]
LEFT JOIN
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS] ON
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] =
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[transactiondate]
LEFT JOIN
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments] ON 
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] =
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[transactiondate]
WHERE
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate]  = @fromdate AND
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] <= @todate
ORDER BY
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[Description],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate]
END

GO
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry Its for MSSQL server 2008

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that `storeno` is integer, even if it's not you can follow the same principle for any other data type. This would be syntactically simple approach but look out for the execution plan:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReportTotals] (
@fromdate VARCHAR(10),
@todate VARCHAR(10),
@storeno INT -- if you want all stores send NULL as @storeno parameter, if you want specific store send its storeno
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[Description],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[amount] AS 'pos',
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[amount] AS 'ecc',
CASE WHEN [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[amount] = [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[amount] THEN 'BALANCED' ELSE 'UNBALANCED' END AS 'status',
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[responce],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[comment]
FROM
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals]
LEFT JOIN
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS] ON
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] =
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[transactiondate]
LEFT JOIN
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments] ON 
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] =
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[transactiondate]
WHERE
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate]  = @fromdate AND
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] <= @todate AND
(@storeno IS NULL OR [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] = @storeno)
ORDER BY
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[Description],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate]
END
```

The other approach that could possibly produce more favorable execution plan could be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReportTotals] (
@fromdate VARCHAR(10),
@todate VARCHAR(10),
@storeno INT -- if you want all stores send NULL as @storeno parameter, if you want specific store send its storeno
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[Description],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[amount] AS 'pos',
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[amount] AS 'ecc',
CASE WHEN [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[amount] = [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[amount] THEN 'BALANCED' ELSE 'UNBALANCED' END AS 'status',
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[responce],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[comment]
INTO #temp
FROM
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals]
LEFT JOIN
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS] ON
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] =
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS].[transactiondate]
LEFT JOIN
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments] ON 
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] =
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[storeno] +
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[comments].[transactiondate]
WHERE
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate]  = @fromdate AND
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] <= @todate 
ORDER BY
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[Description],
[POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate]

IF(@storeno IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    #temp   
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    #temp
    WHERE   storeno = @storeno
END

END
```

This approach involves two SELECT statements and a temporary table but it might execute faster (i.e. might have a better execution plan). Before using any of these in production version of your SP check the execution plans and query cost metric and determine which approach works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReportTotals] (
--your paramets
@storeno your_data_type
....
--Changed WHERE clause
WHERE
  [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate]  = @fromdate AND
  [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[transactiondate] <= @todate AND
  [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno] = ISNULL(@storeno, [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals].[storeno])
```